# wget blocked by iptables in CentOS 5.5 and iptables 1.3.5

Tags: linux, firewall, iptables

Whith this rules I can't use wget to an external address or send emails through an external SMTP server:

```
#!/bin/bash

# Flush all current rules from iptables
iptables -F

# Allow SSH
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --dport 22 -j ACCEPT

iptables -P INPUT DROP
iptables -P FORWARD DROP
iptables -P OUTPUT ACCEPT

# Set access for localhost
iptables -A INPUT -i lo -j ACCEPT

# Accept packets belonging to established and related connections
iptables -A INPUT -m state --state ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j ACCEPT

# Allow incoming web traffic
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --dport 80 -j ACCEPT
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --dport 443 -j ACCEPT

# Save settings
/sbin/service iptables save
```

But if I add this, it works:

```
iptables -A INPUT -p udp -m udp --sport 53 -j ACCEPT
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --sport 80 -j ACCEPT
```

Shouldn't the following rule allow any incoming connection originated by a previous request?

```
iptables -A INPUT -m state --state ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j ACCEPT
```

**EDIT:** when I run the script I get 2 errors:

```
iptables: Unknown error 4294967295
iptables: Unknown error 4294967295
```

I'm using CentOS 5.5 and iptables 1.3.5. Digging more I have found that there is a bug in this version: http://bugs.centos.org/view.php?id=3632 Can this be the cause of the problem?

**EDIT 2:** if I run demsg I get the same message repeated:

```
ip_tables: udp match: only valid for protocol 17
```

**EDIT 3:** Running iptables -L INPUT -v -n after a successfull wget shows:

```
# iptables -L INPUT -v -n
Chain INPUT (policy DROP 0 packets, 0 bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination
   31  2020 ACCEPT     tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           tcp dpt:22
    0     0 ACCEPT     all  --  lo     *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0
    0     0 ACCEPT     tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           tcp dpt:80
    0     0 ACCEPT     tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           tcp dpt:443
    4   938 ACCEPT     udp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           udp spt:53
   12 11439 ACCEPT     tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           tcp spt:80
```

**EDIT 4:** Running sh -x script shows:

```
 # sh -x firewall.conf
+ iptables -F
+ iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --dport 22 -j ACCEPT
+ iptables -P INPUT DROP
+ iptables -P FORWARD DROP
+ iptables -P OUTPUT ACCEPT
+ iptables -A INPUT -i lo -j ACCEPT
+ iptables -A INPUT -m state --state ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j ACCEPT
iptables: Unknown error 4294967295
+ iptables -A OUTPUT -m state --state ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j ACCEPT
iptables: Unknown error 4294967295
+ iptables -A INPUT -m conntrack --ctstate ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j ACCEPT
iptables: Unknown error 4294967295
+ iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --dport 80 -j ACCEPT
+ iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --dport 443 -j ACCEPT
+ /sbin/service iptables save
Saving firewall rules to /etc/sysconfig/iptables:          [  OK  ]
```

Comment: Show us what iptables-save displays. Also, what are your rules "Allow incoming web traffic" for? Do you have local WEB server?

Comment: Hi, when I run iptables-save I get the errors in the first edit of the question and yes, it is a web server.

Answer (score 3):

you dont have any rules in the OUTPUT chain and the default policy for it is DROP, so the initial tcp packets sent by your system when you try to open http or smtp connection get dropped. You need to add rules like these to permit outbound http and smtp for wget and email:

iptables -A OUTPUT -p tcp --dport 80 -m state --state NEW  -j ACCEPT

iptables -A OUTPUT -p tcp --dport 25 -m state --state NEW  -j ACCEPT

you can consolidate them into one rule using multiport:

iptables -A OUTPUT -p tcp -m multiport --dports 25,80 -m state --state NEW  -j ACCEPT

Comment: Edit: nevermind.

Comment: Hi vadimk, I have "iptables -P OUTPUT ACCEPT" so that should allow anything by default. I tried your suggestion but it still doesnt work.

Comment: sorry, my mistake. Since wget works when you add rule that matches source port 80 (the one with -sport 80), then you should focus on the rule that should permit reply packets by matching their state ESTABLISHED. Either state is not created or the rule can not match it. I wonder which iptables command causes that strange error "Unknown error". TRy to run your iptables script like "sh -x script" to see which one it is. May be module "state" is not available on your system. Also to separate firewall and DNS problems try to run wget using ip address of the server instead of the name.

Comment: I run your test and it seems to be there the problem, as you said. So the only solution is to upgrade to a new version, as pepoluan suggests?

Comment: looks like you have two choices: either upgrade iptables to get the fix for this bug or run it stateless with the rule that matches source port 80. The latter has security risks in that it is easy to initiate connection from outside with source port 80 to any port on your machine and this rule will permit it. This renders all other rules in the INPUT chain that protect your server rather useless.

Comment: I decommissioned my last CentOS 5 machine some time ago so I can't check my own configurations, but I lately used rpmforge repositories to upgrade it. Check if they have newer version of iptables and the kernel if you want to avoid building from source: https://rpmrepo.org/RPMforge/Using

Comment: I looked at rpmrepo but they still have the same iptables version. Thanks anyway!

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried

```
iptables -A INPUT -m conntrack --ctstate ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j ACCEPT
```

It may be related to "state" module/kernel extension missing/having-issues/playing-mind-games (?).

May worth a try.

Comment: Hi jliendo, I tried but without luck. Thanks any way.

Answer (score 1):

`iptables -A INPUT -m state --state ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j ACCEPT`

This is only doing connection tracking on data crossing the input chain.  Your connection isn't established yet, you're still doing a three way handshake (TCP three way handshake).  So conntrack is denying the connection as it should.

`iptables -A OUTPUT -m state --state ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j ACCEPT`

should fix it.

Comment: Hi Sean, i tried but it still does not work with your rule.

Comment: Based on your addition of `ip_tables: udp match: only valid for protocol 17` I think there is a problem with the udp traffic coming back in.  For diagnostics, add this `iptables -A INPUT -p udp -j ACCEPT` temporarily and see if it fixes the problem.

Comment: Actually, as a further measure, run this command after you are successful with the wget.  `iptables -L INPUT -v -n`  That will give you counters to show which rules are being matched.  Check to see which one is allowing the return traffic through the chain.

Comment: @Sean no, you got that wrong. In conntrack, ESTABLISHED means a reply to an outgoing packet. conntrack's ESTABLISHED is different from TCP-Established state. This behavior enables conntrack to reat UDP replies as ESTABLISHED.

Comment: Can you run this on a terminal, maybe in screen, while you attempt the wget?  It will show conntrack states for all open connections... `watch -n 0.5 "cat /proc/net/ip_conntrack"` -- It may help diagnose this.  @pepoluan; I stand corrected.  When I learned this information, I was given information and took it at face value without confirming it myself.  I'll be reading over the conntrack docs tomorrow.  Thanks.

Comment: @Sean C, That's plainly wrong stated. Connection tracking is automatical and has no relation to -m state in your firewall.

Comment: Hi Sean, I edited the question with the results. Also tried watch -n 0.5 "cat /proc/net/ip_conntrack" and got "cat: /proc/net/ip_conntrack: No such file or directory"

Comment: That sounds like `ip_conntrack` isn't loaded.  Try `modprobe ip_conntrack`.  If this doesn't work, you need to recompile your kernel with `ip_conntrack` enabled either as a module or compiled into the kernel for connection tracking to work.

Comment: @pepoluan; I've looked into your claims on how conntrack ESTABLISHED is different than TCP-Established, and you're wrong.  When a new connection starts (IE SYN_SENT) conntrack sets a new state for the connection TCP_CONNTRACK_SYN_SENT, conntrack ignores the SYN_ACK and when it sees the ACK it sets the connection to ESTABLISHED.

Comment: @poige, While I can appreciate your comments; adding `-m state` is equivalent to `--modprobe state`, allows access to the connection tracking state.  Per the iptables man page `'state' This  module,  when combined with connection tracking, allows access to the connection tracking state for this packet.`

Comment: Running modprobe ip_conntrack returns "FATAL: Could not load /lib/modules/2.6.18-028stab070.5/modules.dep: No such file or directory". Do you think that recompiling the kernel with ip_conntrack can solve it? How can I do it?

Comment: This is the problem. Your kernel doesn't currently have conntrack compiled-in or as a module. As someone who has never used CentOS, I'll be advising you based on what I understand about RPM managed Linux flavors. Before you begin, take a look under /boot for a file called config-<kernel version>. Grep that file for `CONFIG_NF_CONNTRACK`. What you should see is that the CONNTRACK kernel components are marked with `n`. yum install your kernel sources and copy the config file to your kernel sources -- usually `/usr/src/linux`. Change the CONNTRACK entries from `n` to `m` and run `make`.

Comment: After you run `make` you'll need to run `make modules_install` to install the kernel modules.  Then you can copy the new kernel from `arch/x86/boot/bzImage` to your `/boot` and make a new grub/lilo entry to boot from that kernel.

Comment: @Sean no. *Internally*, conntrack has the SYN_SENT state, which makes it expect a SYN-ACK reply. But you can't specify that state for `-m state`. In this case, ESTABLISHED applies for all kinds of replies: http://netfilter.org/documentation/HOWTO//packet-filtering-HOWTO-7.html#ss7.3 If that's not the case, then please explain how my servers and firewalls are able to accept SYN-ACKs when I don't put any specific --sport rule, just a `-m state --state ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j ACCEPT`

Comment: Here's a very detailed explanation: http://www.linuxtopia.org/Linux_Firewall_iptables/x1347.html the next page describes the *userland states* in the case of TCP connections. It explicitly says that *"the connection tracking code does not really follow the flow of the TCP connection, from the users viewpoint. Once it has seen one packet(the SYN), it considers the connection as NEW. Once it sees the return packet(SYN/ACK), it considers the connection as ESTABLISHED."*

Comment: It appears as though I was confusing the state machine with the with actual conntrack module.  *Within conntrack, there definitely exists a state called TCP_CONNTRACK_SYN_SENT* and it does not change until the three-way handshake is complete.  The state engine, as you've indicated, does consider the connection as ESTABLISHED once the return SYN/ACK hits the PREROUTING chain.  Does this discussion help the original author?  No.  But you can feel comforted that you educated me on the difference between the iptables state engine and the conntrack module.

Comment: @Sean heh, no offense meant. Just want to prevent people from using iptables as a stateless firewall. All's well that ends well :)

Comment: Thank you guys, I have learned a lot with your comments, altough hey are totally out of my league :).  @Sean: Will I lose the ability to update the kernel with yum if I recompile as you say?

Comment: @Dawkins.  I don't know enough about package management on RPM-based distributions to answer this question.  I assume that if you don't uninstall the kernel provided kernel, the package manager will update it as normal.  This is a question for a CentOS admin.

Answer (score 1):

I think you ought to update your `iptables`; mine's already version 1.4.10.

For instance, the 'Unknown error 4294967295' has been fixed in 1.3.6: http://ftp.netfilter.org/pub/iptables/changes-iptables-1.3.6.txt

Of course, this will very probably need a kernel update.

Comment: I did a complete yum update and still have the 1.3.5 version. It is the last version available from the repos. Is there another way to update it than building from source?

Comment: Hmm... that's tough then. the 'tricky' part with `iptables` is that it's intimately tied to the `netfilter` code in the kernel. if the repo does not have a newer version, you have to build from source so that it 'adapts' to your kernel. I am not familiar with CentOS; does it have user-repos?  If so, try searching for a newer `iptables` from them.

Answer (score 0):

You should "pair" the rules between INPUT and OUTPUT

Since outgoing wget is requesting to use port 21,80 and/or 443 TCP OUTPUT, and needs permission for "incoming INPUT" from sourceport 20,21,80 and/or 443 try this :

```
# rule OUT first :
iptables -A OUTPUT -p tcp -o ethX -d 0/0 -m multiport --dport 21,80,443 -m state --state NEW,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT

# rule for "coming back" from OUT to INPUT :
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp -i ethX -s 0/0 -m multiport --sport 20,21,80,443 -m state --state ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
```

where ethX is your external eth interface (eth0 eth1 or whatever)

Rule for sending mails thru outer SMTP? Do the same, just change the dport and sport on each rule above

I hope that helps, it works for me.

Btw, My iptables is v1.3.5, and my default INPUT OUTPUT FORWARD policies set to DROP :-)